# Use Zxing Library on PreviewFrame for Augmented Reality

Tags: java, android, augmented-reality, zxing

Can someone tell me how I can use the Zxing Library for an Augmented Reality App? I know the easiest way to use Zxing is via Intent, but I need the Camera View so I can not use the barcode App.

I have a `SurfaceHolder.Callback` which is added to the main activity and overwrites following method:

```
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    mCamera = Camera.open();

    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Can not set surface holder");
    }

    mCamera.startPreview();

    Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
    parameters.setPreviewSize(1280, 720);
    parameters.setPictureSize(1280, 720);
    mCamera.setParameters(parameters);

    QrCodeReader reader = new QrCodeReader();
    mCamera.setPreviewCallback(reader);
}
```

The setted picture size has to be available because it is in the list `parameters.getSupportedPictureSizes()`.

And this method in the `QrCodeReader` class which implements `PreviewCallback`:

```
private Result result;
private MultiFormatReader reader = new MultiFormatReader();
private boolean init = false;

public QrCodeReader(){
        Hashtable<DecodeHintType, Object> hints = new Hashtable<DecodeHintType,
              Object>();
    hints.put(DecodeHintType.TRY_HARDER, Boolean.TRUE);
    reader.setHints(hints);
}

@Override
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    PlanarYUVLuminanceSource source = new PlanarYUVLuminanceSource(data,
          1280, 720, 0, 0, 1280, 720, true);
    HybridBinarizer hybBin = new HybridBinarizer(source);
    BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(hybBin);

try {
        result = reader.decodeWithState(bitmap);
        Log.d("Result", "Result found!");
    } catch (NotFoundException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "NotFoundException");
    } finally {
        reader.reset();
    }
}
```

The Logcat only shows `NotFoundException`.

Comment: What has the barcode scanner ZXING to do with Augmented Reality?

Comment: I need the QR-Code more or less as a marker to show 3D-Objects and information in real-time.

Comment: In this case you may need to download the source code and try to extract the QR code detection.

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to mention that I already do that. The line reader.decode(bitmap) calls the QR code detection from Zxing.

Answer (score 1):

`NotFoundException` is normal. If the frame doesn't have a barcode, that's the result. This doesn't mean anything is wrong per se. Keep scanning.

Comment: Yes, that's true, but as long as I keep scanning there is no result anytime. I printed a very big QR Code but still no result ...

Comment: The solution above is working now! Thank you for your answers! There was a stupid fault. I only had to switch the picture parameters.